# Script failing for restoration of database, as unable to proceed further

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I want to include * as mentioned below in double inverted commas, but i am not able to find the file. When i remove the inverted double inverted commas it works.

```
$CONTROL=/bkp/Test/back/13_Mar_2018/
ls -lrt "$CONTROL\*controlfile";
```

Comment: What have you tried to do so far, what do want to happen, and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I am trying to create a script where

Comment: I am trying to create a script which should call the controlfile as the file contains "Test13032018_970629552_kfstl8dg_1_1_" should be excluded and search only for controlfile
[oracle@ ~]$ ls -lrt "/home/oracle/bkp/Test/back/13_Mar_2018/Test13032018_970629552_kfstl8dg_1_1_controlfile"
-rw-r----- 1 oracle bseerp 2375680 Mar 15 08:56 /home/oracle/bkp/Test/back/13_Mar_2018/Test13032018_970629552_kfstl8dg_1_1_controlfile
[oracle@ ~]$ ls -lrt "/home/oracle/bkp/Test/back/13_Mar_2018/*controlfile"
ls: cannot access /home/oracle/bkp/Test/back/13_Mar_2018/*controlfile: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

[Pathname expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_06) doesn't work within quotes. However, you can do something like this:

```
CONTROL=/bkp/Test/back/13_Mar_2018/
ls -lrt "$CONTROL"*controlfile
```

- `$CONTROL` is quoted to prevent side effects like [field splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05).
- `*` is not quoted to allow pathname expansion.
- `controlfile` doesn't need to be quoted, but you can quote it if you want.

Comment: I am unable to call it, as mentioned below. Please help.
export $CONTROL='/bkp01/oracle/PRODERP/backupset/2018_Mar_13/'
ls -lrt $CONTROL*controlfile;

Comment: @James What do you exactly mean by "call it"? Do you want to run the controlfile as if it were a command/script? If yes, how many controlfiles do you have? If there are two or more, do you want to run each of them or just a specific one? By the way, feel free to unmark my answer as accepted and change the title of the question or ask a new one; it seems that the `*` was not the part we should focus on.

Comment: I want the below mentioned commands to be written in a script where 'Test13032018_970629552_kfstl8dg_1_1_' will keep changing.
Hence, i am planning to insert * infront of controlfile,so that it executes the restore controlfile command.
I have only control file which is taken as a backup
rman TARGET $USER/$PASS  <<EOF
run {
startup nomount;
restore controlfile from '/home/oracle/bkp/Test/back/13_Mar_2018/Test13032018_970629552_kfstl8dg_1_1_controlfile';
sql "alter database mount";
restore database;
recover database;
}
exit;
EOF

Comment: @James Please add further information to the text of your question. The question does not mention executing anything other than an assignment and `ls`.

Comment: I have been trying to create a script which will be used for automation where the rman commands in oracle is unable to find the controlfile,as the control file location must be specified in inverted commas. The text before controlfile keeps changing whenever backup happens, so i want only control file should be picked from the particular path instead of mentioning the entire texts before control file. If my restore commands finds my controlfile then my script will start working, otherwise i have to manually change the path and file name before running the script.